# moved php website from linux to Windows

Tags: php, windows, linux

I have to move a website from a shared hosting on Linux to a VPS running Windows.
Nothing works.. but when I add a new line above `<?php` it works a little bit.

I'm getting errors like headers already sent etc..

Any thoughts on this? Suggestions? This is really getting me pissed..

edit:
0. not seeing anything ( file index.php not found ) 
1. adding newline , script(index.php) is found. 
2. Errors : Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at C:...config.php on line 134 ( where I start my session )

Comment: "It doesn't work" and "works a little bit" are *never* good error descriptions. Please describe what goes wrong, what error messages you get, etc.

Comment: Thoughts?  Yes, you didn't post enough information.  Suggestions?  Don't get pissed off, try posting these errors that you're getting.  You simply have a difference of configuration, and if your script isn't sending headers before content, you have other problems as well.

Comment: 0. not seeing anything ( file index.php not found )
1. adding newline , script(index.php) is found.
2. Errors : rning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at C:\...config.php on line 134 ( where I start my session )

Comment: The second file/line reference (not the one you start the session in, the other one) will show you where the output started.

Comment: Most probably a EOL (end of line) problem (eg quite easy to solve) but you need to dig a bit more into your problem analysis.

Answer (score 1):

The [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) is probably your problem

Comment: any quick suggestion on how to solve it? I'm on a deadline here ..
Never expected these problems ..

Comment: You need to confirm the problem first - open a broken file in something that can see the BOM - notepad++ for example.